# using the `auto` keyword with STL iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, auto

I'm following [this](https://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-auto-decltype-return-value-after-function.html) tutorial for using the `auto` keyword with STL iterators.

It says that this syntax is OK for C++ 11.

```
vector<int> vec;
auto itr = vec.iterator(); // instead of vector<int>::iterator itr
```

However, I get this compile error when I try it?

> error: invalid use of ‘std::vector::iterator’

Comment: There are a great many errors in that tutorial. I suggest not reading it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial is wrong. `iterator` is a *type* member, not a *function* member, in all the collection classes. It is the *return type* of some of `vector`'s member functions

What the tutorial *probably* means to write is

```
vector<int> vec;
auto itr = vec.begin(); // itr is of type std::vector<int>::iterator
```